# Send data between database and Apache Cordova app in a secure way

Tags: architecture, database, data, apache, server-security

I'm developing a Cordova app and I've got the UI ready but I need data to my app from a database. For example I want my cordova app to include user authentication when the user opens the app which means, I have to access my database in some way to check the user input. I would also like to get data from the database and show in the app such as the members information, ranking and so on. How do I do this in a easy and proper way? Am I right when I say that there is not a good thing to access a database directly from the javascript in the cordova app, for security reasons?

Is the solution through a architecture that looks like this?

Cordova app(In Google play) --> Application Server --> Database

Answer (score 2):

Your proposed solution is the most typical and commended strategy, yes. Use HTTPS for the secure communication, proper server-side checks for other aspects of security (and not saving plain-text usernames and passwords on the device for yet another consideration of security). Direct access of the database on the server is "not done", [mostly because the database applications are not designed for such a use case either in terms of usability, tool/library support, or security](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/180012/is-there-any-reason-not-to-go-directly-from-client-side-javascript-to-a-database/310587#310587).

Your application server and database can be pretty much anything you want it to be, as through an app you will most likely use something like REST (or old-fashioned GET/POST without the fancy bits) to access it.